# Problem with @use Compiling SCSS with Webpack (@import used to works fine)

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass

I compile my SCSS with webpack:

```
entry: {
        style: "./css/main.scss",
        [...]
},
    output: {
        [...],
        path: resolve(__dirname, "./assets")
    },
[...]
rules: [
{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
[...]
plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "main.css",
        }),
        new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
    ],
```

My main.scss:

```
@use "variables";
[...]
@use "accueil";
```

My issue is that variables in variables.scss are not recognized in my accueil.scss when compiling.
I used to @import (which still works fine), but I've heard that @import is depreciated, so what's the proper option to @use and still have my variables in one file?

here's the terminal log:

```
ERROR in ./css/main.scss (./css/main.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./css/main.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined variable.
    ╷
138 │     width: $largeurBox;
    │            ^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  css\accueil.scss 138:12  @use
  css\main.scss 6:1        root stylesheet
 @ ./css/main.scss

ERROR in ./css/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined variable.
    ╷
138 │     width: $largeurBox;
    │            ^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
```

I tried: `@use "variables" as *;` in my main.scss which doesn't work.

Actual solutions (which I don't like):
Put
`@use "variables" as *;`
in every scss file.

Or
`@import instead of @use`.